# The value or constructor n is not defined

Tags: .net, function, f#, functional-programming

I am new to this functional programming language f#, and while there might be several issues with this small code, I am just curious about why it wont run.

```
let sum n : int -> int = s
let mutable s = 1
while s <= n do
 s <- n(n+1)/2
 printf "%A " s
let result = sum 4
```

It gives me the error code FS0039: The value or constructor n is not defined. I dont understand why. When I call the function sum and assign it to result, I pass the argument 4 (which is n).

Can you tell me what you see?

Thank you.

I want to make the function recursive:

```
let rec recSum (n:int):int =
 if n > 0 then
  recSum n * (n+1)/2
  printf "%A " n
 else 
  n
recSum 4
```

But I cant make it return an int. It keeps returning a unit.

Comment: bad formatting? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In very simple terms your function is the following:

```
let sum n =
    let s = n * (n+1)/2
    printf "%A " s

let result = sum 4
```

In even simpler terms if you want to annotate it and be explicit about  types:

```
let sum' (n:int):int =
    n * (n+1)/2

sum' 4
```

The `(n:int)` specifies the type of the function argument, the second `:int` specificies the output of the function. So sum' is a function that takes and int and returns an int. So now you can do something like this:

```
[1..4] |> List.map sum'
```

The naming could be better, like `numOfCorrel` or something like that. 
Now it's possible that you are after something else, in that case please specify your algorithm or at least the expected output for your input.

**Working version of original Question:**

```
let sum2 (n:int):int = 
    let mutable s = 1
    while s <= n do
        s <- n * (n+1)/2
    s

let result = sum2 4
```

In this case `sum2` takes an `int` and returns and `int`. If you do put `printfn` inside your function, that will print the result and return `()`, unit. Your original function in its first line doesn't make much sense: it's equivalent to saying: I'm a function that takes and int and returns an int and I'm equal to `s`. Obviously as there is no `s` value defined above the F# compiler will complain. For a very quick intro please read [F# Syntax](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/series/expressions-and-syntax.html) and various docs on [Visual F#](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/articles/fsharp/tour).

Returning unit, shadowing s inside the function:

```
let s = 4
let sum3 (n:int): unit = 
    let mutable s = 1
    while s <= n do
        s <- n * (n+1)/2
    printfn "%A" ("s = " + (string s))
sum3 4
s
```

Comment: Yes that is correct. And I see it is actually working without the while loop. Interesting. But if I did need to get my code running including the while loop, how would I go about the errors I am getting? When I added the '*' operator I fixed the "n is not defined issue" but got "s is not defined instead"

Comment: You would rarely use while loops, although it's possible that you actually do need use for/while loops and mutable variables for performance reasons. This combination is very imperative and you are better to avoid in the beginning. I purposely didn't edit your Q, but let me paste a working version into the Answer that mimicks your question.

Comment: @kthonenice there you go.

Comment: Thanks a lot man! I know that my first line didn't make any sense, but unlike you, I am not able to write a function like this:
let sum n =.... 

For some reason it gives me an error when I do that and just tells me that sum is not defined. However when I copy your code it does run and gives me the correct output

Comment: The 's' you added in the last line, is that to force the return type to be an int instead of a unit?

Comment: Your while returns unit, but in the signature you have int as the return type of the function. So you have two choices, either rewrite the signature to return unit, or return s, which is an int. Assuming you want to assign it to  a variable, it's better to return something than nothing. Considering we have defined s within the function it won't be available outside the function, so in case you return unit, you won't be able to access. Try it.

Comment: F# type inference will take care of this stuff, so you don't (usually) need to be too explicit about the input and output types. Hence I left off the signature from the first version and it will work.

Comment: What if I were to make the same function recursive? I cant seem to get around the function not working due to the fact it returns unit

Answer (score 1):

You should have n*(n+1) - missing '*' between operands.

Answer (score 1):

In this case

```
s <- n(n+1)/2
```

will be treated as calling n like a function hence the error message. You should write

```
s <- n*(n+1)/2
```

instead.

Comment: Oh yeah! That fixed the "n is not defined problem" but it now gives me "s is not defined" instead? s is set to 1, so what is the problem here?

Comment: Alright so I made the variable s global, and I am now getting the error message: FS0001: This expression was expected to have type int -> int, but here has type int.

I was wondering about this. Can you please elaborate on this? 
I understand my function like this:
sum takes an argument n of the type int, which then should return an int = s. However I think I have the wrong idea. (Hence the error)